# The default appengine service account does not have a client_id. Why or?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, service-accounts

I can use the default service account `<appengine_app_id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` to get an access_token and make a request.

The oauth provider of the receiving appenine app receives '`anonymous`' for the `get_client_id(SCOPE)`. I use this SCOPE = `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"`

Making the request:

```
access_token = app_identity.get_access_token(SCOPE)[0]    
response = urlfetch.fetch(
        "https://my-other.appspot.com/provider",
        method=urlfetch.POST,
        payload=...,
        follow_redirects=False,
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json",
                 "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token})
```

Handle the request:

```
class ProviderHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        logging.info('app_id=' + self.request.headers['X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid'])
        token_audience = oauth.get_client_id(SCOPE)  # anonymous ??
```

When I create a new service account, furnish a new private key and use:

```
        credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(<json_file_name>, SCOPE)
        acees_token = credentials.get_access_token().access_token
```

it works fine.

Comment: If you're calling from App Engine, why not use Application Default Credentials?

Comment: I could have and will have worked, but I tried to use the default which is returned by  app_identity. Question: if the Application Default Credentials are set by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable, will app_identity use this default credentials service account?